# Drag and Drop functionality in ipad

Tags: ios

I am developing a iPad application in which requires drag and drop image from UIScrollView to a text field in a UIWebView. I have gone through the documentation found Drag and Drop topics for cocoa. But when implementing the protocol for drag and drop i am getting errors. Blow is my code and any help is appreciated.

```
@implementation drangAndDropSampleViewController

@synthesize scrollView1, scrollView2;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    return [super initWithFrame:frame];
}


-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
    cloud.center = location;
    //scrollView1.center = location;
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}


- (void) touchesEnded: (NSSet *) touches withEvent: (UIEvent *) event { 
    // If not dragging, send event to next responder
    if (!self.dragging) 
        [self.nextResponder touchesEnded: touches withEvent:event]; 
    else
        [super touchesEnded: touches withEvent: event];
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We can't help you if you don't tell us what errors you are getting, and where those errors are occurring.